# How to get the combination of values from different columns in one table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't want to insert any row in the table, but just want to get the combination results.

For example, the columns are A,B,C.

```
Value set for A is {1,2}

Value set for B is {a,b}

Value set for C is {!,@}

The combination I want are:

1 a !
1 a @
1 b !
1 b @
2 a !
2 a @
2 b !
2 b @
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your example schema correctly as:

```
CREATE TABLE test (A varchar(10), B varchar(10),C varchar(10));
INSERT INTO test (A, B, C) VALUES ('1', 'a', '!');
INSERT INTO test (A, B, C) VALUES ('2', 'b', '@');
```

then you can do:

```
SELECT 
  T.A, 
  T2.B, 
  T3.C
FROM 
  test T
  CROSS JOIN test T2
  CROSS JOIN test T3
ORDER BY 
  T.a, 
  T2.b, 
  T3.c;
```

This uses a CROSS JOIN operation, which produces the Cartesian Product of the two tables - i.e. every row matched with every other row. It's a lesser-used part of SQL. There's a good explanation of it here: http://www.w3resource.com/oracle/joins/oracle-cross-join.php

See a working example of my code here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91137/3

Answer (score 0):

The table we have:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(   a NUMBER, 
    b VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    c VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
)
```

So, query you need:

```
SELECT t.a, t2.b, t3.c FROM test t
  CROSS JOIN test t2
  CROSS JOIN test t3
  ORDER BY t.a, t2.b, t3.c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross join on same table. here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eefff/6)

if schema is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `A` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `B` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `C` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `A`, `B`, `C`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'a', '!'),
  ('2', '2', 'b', '@');
```

you can use

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.a,' ',t2.B,' ',t3.c)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A FROM docs) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT B FROM docs) AS t2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT C FROM docs) AS t3
order by t1.a, t2.b, t3.c
```